# Android NetworkOnMainThreadException inside of AsyncTask

Tags: android, google-calendar-api, google-api-java-client

I have a problem on ICS when I try to use google calendar api. To get a list of events, I have a AsyncTask and inside doInBackground() I make the service calls but still I receive the NetworkOnMainThreadException error.

Here is my code:

I call my AsyncTask like this:

```
new GoogleCalendarEvents().execute(new Object());
```

And my AsyncTask looks like this:

```
private class GoogleCalendarEvents extends AsyncTask<Object, Object, Object> {

        @Override
        protected Object doInBackground(Object... objects) {

            OAuthManager manager = OAuthManager.getInstance();
            /* login to google api and get the auth token */
            manager.doLogin("", true, mActivity, new OAuthManager.AuthHandler() {
                @Override
                public void handleAuth(Account account, String authToken) {
                    if (account != null) {
                        /* create a google Calendar service if the returned account is not null */
                        com.google.api.services.calendar.Calendar service = CalendarServiceBuilder.build(OAuthManager.getInstance().getAuthToken());
                        try {

                            /* get the list of events for the primary calendar */
                            /* ---------HERE THE APP IS CRUSHING  --------- */
                            mEvents = service.events().list(mCalendarId).execute();

                            while (true) {
                                /* get the next page token if any */
                                String pageToken = mEvents.getNextPageToken();

                                if (pageToken != null && !pageToken.equals("")) {
                                    /* if there are other pages, get the next page */
                                    Events newPageEvents = service.events().list(mCalendarId)
                                            .setPageToken(pageToken).execute();

                                    for (Event event : newPageEvents.getItems()) {
                                        /* loop through all the events and add them into the mEvents  */
                                        mEvents.put(event.getId(), event);
                                    }

                                } else {
                                    break;
                                }
                            }
                            /* make sure we wont have memory leaks */
                            mActivity = null;
                            /* notify the caller that the calendar events are ready */
                            mEventsReceiverCallback.calendarEventsReceived(true);
                            mEventsReceiverCallback = null;

                        } catch (IOException e) {
                            /* let the user know that the event could not be created */
                            Utility.showInformationDialog(mActivity, mActivity.getString(R.string.error),
                                    mActivity.getString(R.string.error_message_bad_request_get_events));
                            /* make sure we wont have memory leaks */
                            mActivity = null;
                            /* print the error into the log */
                            e.printStackTrace();
                            /* notify the caller that the manager could not get the calendar events */
                            mEventsReceiverCallback.calendarEventsReceived(false);
                            mEventsReceiverCallback = null;

                        }

                    } else {

                        /* le the user know that the event could not be created */
                        Utility.showInformationDialog(mActivity, mActivity.getString(R.string.error),
                                mActivity.getString(R.string.error_message_connection));
                        /* make sure we wont have memory leaks */
                        mActivity = null;
                        /* notify the caller that the manager could not get the calendar events */
                        mEventsReceiverCallback.calendarEventsReceived(false);
                        mEventsReceiverCallback = null;

                    }
                }
            });

            return null;
        }

    }
```

And the log:

```
02-22 10:32:08.597: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(13924): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
        android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException
        at android.os.StrictMode$AndroidBlockGuardPolicy.onNetwork(StrictMode.java:1099)
        at java.net.InetAddress.lookupHostByName(InetAddress.java:391)
        at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByNameImpl(InetAddress.java:242)
        at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName(InetAddress.java:220)
        at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultClientConnectionOperator.openConnection(DefaultClientConnectionOperator.java:137)
        at org.apache.http.impl.conn.AbstractPoolEntry.open(AbstractPoolEntry.java:164)
        at org.apache.http.impl.conn.AbstractPooledConnAdapter.open(AbstractPooledConnAdapter.java:119)
        at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.execute(DefaultRequestDirector.java:360)
        at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:555)
        at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:487)
        at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:465)
        at com.google.api.client.http.apache.ApacheHttpRequest.execute(ApacheHttpRequest.java:58)
        at com.google.api.client.http.HttpRequest.execute(HttpRequest.java:639)
        at com.google.api.client.http.json.JsonHttpClient.execute(JsonHttpClient.java:257)
        at com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.GoogleClient.execute(GoogleClient.java:121)
        at com.google.api.client.http.json.JsonHttpRequest.executeUnparsed(JsonHttpRequest.java:67)
        at com.google.api.services.calendar.Calendar$Events$List.execute(Calendar.java:2643)
        at /* here is the error, I think */com.google.calendar.manager.business.CalendarEventProvider$GoogleCalendarEvents$1.handleAuth(CalendarEventProvider.java:118)
        at com.google.calendar.manager.utils.OAuthManager$1.run(OAuthManager.java:194)
        at android.accounts.AccountManager$10.run(AccountManager.java:1264)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:605)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4424)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:784)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:551)
        at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

[Here](http://code.google.com/p/google-http-java-client/wiki/Android#HTTP_Transport) says that I have to use  AndroidHttp.newCompatibleTransport() as the transport class, and I do use it in my CalendarServiceBuilder.

What could cause this error and how I can solve the problem?

Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems the problem was in the manifest.. I had this attribute in the uses-sdk tag:

```
android:targetSdkVersion="10"
```

After I removed this attribute, the app worked.

Comment: it sounds a bit strange. This kind of exception has been introduced in order to avoid long running task in the UI Thread. I will suggest to check again your code in order to be sure that everything that will require network access is not performed on the UI thread. Anything in the onPostExecute?

Comment: I double checked, thank you for the tip, I know why that error should start and I tried to make a simple google request with the adnroid sdk HttpGet method and actualy worked without a problem and if I switched the code within that asyncTask with the google calendar one, the error appeared.. after I changed that in the manifest, it worked

Comment: OMG, that really worked. I had the same problem then I removed the android:targetSdkVersion attribute. Now the app is loading fine.

Answer (score 0):

Are you testing this on the emulator? For some reason I have the same issue when testing on the emulator while streaming a .mpjeg within AsyncTask; however when I test it on a device it works fine.

It may be an emulator issue; however it could also be something with ICS (I emulator 4.0.3 but run 2.3.7 CM7b257 on my phone) but give it a try as that could very well be your issue.

Comment: it works on your 2.3.7 because the NetworkOnMainThreadException
 has been in android since api 11

Comment: I test this on a Nexus S device with Android 4.0.3

Comment: @blackbelt Thanks for the info - hadn't even thought to check that. Interesting though since I have everything inside the background task; I'll have to recheck that project later on.